# django celery raise exception : ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I used redis, celery, django, django-celery-results

but i got an error log in /var/log/celery/celery.log

```
Pool callback raised exception: ImproperlyConfigured('settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.',)
```

folloing is my project structure

```
  - proj
      - config
        - settings 
            __init__.py
           base.py
           local.py
           production.py
      - proj
        __init__.py
        celery.py
```

and following is proj/proj/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.production')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
  print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

and following is proj/config/settings/production.py

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_secret("DATABASES", "NAME"),
        'USER': get_secret("DATABASES", "USER"),
        "PASSWORD":get_secret("DATABASES", "PASSWORD"),
        "HOST":get_secret("DATABASES", "HOST"),
        "PORT":get_secret("DATABASES", "PORT")
    },
}

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Celery Setting
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
#CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
#CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
#CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'
```

I have no idea what the problem is...
Please help me...

Comment: the issue comes from your DATABASES configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself in the following way

```
export 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'='config.settings.production'
```